# SMS sent automatically with message "HouslistacZ GMAIL" to unknown number

Tags: sms, gmail, malware

My phone has been sending the following message automatically about once a week since I bought it 1 year ago. As far as I see, there is no scheduled time for sending this message and the message context always has been the same. Also, it seems that the recipient is invalid, since I got "(no recipient)" every time it's sent.

Is it a virus? How do I remove it?

[image: sms screenshot]

Comment: It does seem like spam.  Google has a lot of results for domains registered to `houslistacz@gmail.com` so it's possible it's related to a botnet or something.  Did you buy the phone used?  Have you tried a factory reset?

Comment: @MatthewRead I am the first owner of it and I bought it about one year ago.I haven't tried a factory reset yet but I am going to .

Comment: I've just reset the phone but immediately the message has been sent again.I have just found out I  can block "unknown messages" in spam messages section on the phone.But how can I do it without sending the first message.

Comment: Surprisingly, searching for "houslistacz gmail" (not the email address) returns very little hint, so we need some clarification: 1) are you connected to the internet (WiFi/mobile)? 2) if yes, is it always on the same connection, or WiFi only, or mobile only? 3) if yes, try turning off the internet for a week or more. 4) if it's still sending, then it might be scheduled offline by an app. You can check the app, but hold on since it might be too complex for common user ([how to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522792/get-list-of-active-pendingintents-in-alarmmanager/6523295#6523295))

Comment: @Andrew T. I am mostly connected to the internet via WiFi and yes I almost always use the same connection.

Comment: @AndrewT. The first message was sent 12 hours ago just after I had reset the phone and then again almost exactly 12 hours later the message was sent . I suspect  I have installed a spy program indeliberately because whenever I take pictures, the message is sent in 12 hours otherwise it could take long but interesting thing even though I reset the phone, I have reset twice, the message is sent immediately after  the phone turns on.